# Api or command line access to a Jenkins Config setting?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins

Specifically I'm trying to access the SeleniumHQ (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Seleniumhq+Plugin) jar file setting. I know I can parse it from the xml file but I was hoping it'd be as simple as something like ${seleniumRunner} but it's not. Is there a cleaner API call or variable structure that will call this for me?

```
more ../hudson.plugins.seleniumhq.SeleniumhqBuilder.xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<hudson.plugins.seleniumhq.SeleniumhqBuilder_-DescriptorImpl plugin="seleniumhq@0.4-Custom">
  <seleniumRunner>/var/lib/jenkins/tools/selenium-server-standalone-2.44.0.jar</seleniumRunner>
</hudson.plugins.seleniumhq.SeleniumhqBuilder_-DescriptorImpl>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use the the [groovy script console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console)

Which can be accessed from curl

```
$ curl -d "script=<your_script_here>" http://jenkins/script
```

This [example](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Add+a+Maven+Installation%2C+Tool+Installation%2C+Modify+System+Config) modifies the maven config

```
a=Jenkins.instance.getExtensionList(hudson.tasks.Maven.DescriptorImpl.class)[0];
b=(a.installations as List);
b.add(new hudson.tasks.Maven.MavenInstallation("MAVEN3", "/home/apache-maven-3", []));
a.installations=b
a.save()
```